# Scenekit: Dynamic Modification of Geometries

Tags: xcode, scenekit, vertices, scngeometry

For my 3D game about a spaceship flying in a cave, I need to modify the geometries that the cave is built from. As stated in earlier posts, the cave is constructed from circular shapes by putting one shape behind another to create a tube-like surrounding, in which the ship is maneuvering. The shapes are tilted in small angles so the tube is curved. However, the tilting of the shapes creates overlapping parts that disturb the tube's appearance.
Thus, the geometries of the shapes need to be adjusted - shorter in the inside of the curves and longer on the outside.

At first I thought that a 'vertex shader' could be the solution, but I learnt from a previous post that this describes something else: an algorithm modifying the visual appearance of the shape, but not creating a modified geometry that could be used i.e. as a physicsBody (which is required for correct collision detection).
So now I am seeking help in the dynamic modification of SCNgeometries. At this point in time, I have never programmed anything alike, but if I understand correctly, I need to read and modify the vertices of the geometry.

[image: 2 rings each containing 12 rectangles - to be modified]

There is one more thing to mention: the rings themselves are not a one-piece, but made from a number of plane segments, so the routine would need to (internally) create the higher-order structure (the ring) first, before it is applied on the same.
On the attached picture, you can see the 2 rings (from outside).
Can anyone share an (as simple as possible) description or a link, where I could find the information I am looking for?

(I positioned the rings for better clarity - they are not in the correct position for simple merging)

Comment: For such stuff, I really recommend you to build your tube like in Blender or whatever external program. Putting the tube together using scene nodes for each segment will quickly push Scenekit to its limits.

Comment: Ok, assuming I do this - using a ring I created earlier in blender - how to I modify the single vertices?

Comment: do you mean modifying using scenekit or blender? What I mean: create the whole tube in blender. it can be very long and curvy. assign static concavePolyhedron physics body, and you will be able to move a dynamic physics node inside it. (and put the normals inside the tube, and make the visual rendering eventually double sided)

Comment: I haven‘t thought that far. I think the compromise could be the solution: the ring is created with blender, and a number of these is used to make the tube (with a concavePolyhedron for each ring). And I already have an editor for the caves, with functional tunnel parts, enemies, etc. All this is working, only working with the tunnel-made-of-rings principle.

Comment: As ZAY suggested you could create the entire tube (e.g. one per level) and load that 3d model. Looks relatively low poly so wouldn’t have a major impact on performance. A good reason to create the tube in code is the need to generate random/unique caves. In that case I suggest creating the tube in code entirely. Calculate the vertex positions for each ring, where ring is just an edge ring (a cross section, not a ring of polygons), then connect those vertices with triangles/strips/polygons (what you called plane segments) by feeding that info into a SCNGeometry for a SCNNode.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Xartec. I have been working on my project for years now, and I am very happy with how far I have come. The idea of creating entirely by code is intriguing - especially from the perspective ‚Rogue-like‘. Yet, I have found that the putting together of ready-made parts also offers this (whereas the 3D-model clearly doesn‘t). The tunnels as they are now also have branches and the rings are not really rings, but can be oval or even complex structures. Performance is not a problem, as only the visible rings are displayed (others are hidden).

Comment: So, at this point, the one thing that I need is a method to modify single vertices of the planes or alternatively the rings before I put them on the screen.

Comment: @ULI SceneKit doesn’t offer the functionality you’re looking for. Technically, you could read the vertices from the scngeometry of two adjacent cave sections, determine the edge rings you want to modify, and build your own way to connect them, then feed back into another scnnode. You’d essentially be building part of a 3d modeling app and it won’t perform well. Instead, let me suggest another option: multiply/copy the cave sections for every possibly angle, feasible only if you limit the number of possible different angles.

Comment: @Xartec To build the cave sections for every possible angle and limit the number of possible angles was the first option I tried, but this was limiting too much whereas the workload was incredible. As mentioned above, there are plenty of shapes that need to be adjusted. Which is the reason for my question in the first place. I have tried the options that ZAY and you suggested before I came to the one I am working with right now.

Comment: So let‘s assume I try the ‚3d modeling app‘ variant - how would I read out the vertex-positions of the concerned nodes?